# Is it possible to do large-scale projects with Node.js

Tags: node.js

Hi everyone I wonder if **Node.js** provides doing large projects like **[Disqus](http://disqus.com)** and **[Ghost](https://ghost.org)**.

Is this possible or do we have to use minimum 1 language as additional like Python, Django, PHP?

Comment: Yes. But depends on the project.

Comment: @Quad, I have already said it. Like disqus, ghost.

Comment: http://yahooeng.tumblr.com/nodeweekly `and will soon power most of Yahoo.`

Comment: Disqus and ghost are quite different projects both in scale and purpose, but again YES, it's possible to write something like disqus and ghost. But of course , possibility and suitability are different things.

Comment: It's strange to ask if it's possible to write something like Ghost with node.js, because Ghost IS written with node.js

Comment: @vkurchatkin is it written only with Node.js?

Comment: @ozer the backend part, yes. the frontend is ember.js as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS is a powerful, fast developing technology. It allows you to make anything you want as if you write in PHP ot Python. But there are also some nuances that can make you doubt about it, and you can read [a good article about them](https://coderwall.com/p/diokxg). You will see that Node.js is suitable for big projects.

From my experience, the **main** trouble when you develop for Node.js even in small projects is

**"Callback Hell"**

Node.JS is mainly asynchronous, so performing consecutive actions turns into adding one statement in the callback function of another statement, which is situated in callback function of another...

```
doAsync1(function (callback) {
  doAsync2(function (callback) {
    doAsync3(function (callback) {
      doAsync4(function (callback) {
    })
  })
})
```

This is good for performance, because the server is not locked waiting for result, but it is really painful for your eyes, especially when you need to perform large sequential operations, and it slows the development speed. [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) can help you with it.

But everything else about Node.js is great. Using a framework such as [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and a lot of modules **(it is not Python, Node.js does not have a big standard library with a lot of cool things in it)** will allow you to build large projects.

Comment: thanks for reply. You are really helped me. But I am stil confused. Express is enough to make user login-logout systems?